# What is the window length of moving average trend in seasonal.seasonal_decompose package?

Tags: python, moving-average

I am using `seasonal.seasonal_decompose` in python.
What is the window length of moving average trend in `seasonal.seasonal_decompose` package?
Based on my results, I think it is 25. But how can I be sure? how can I change this window length?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The "freq" part defines the window of moving average. Still not sure how the program choose the window when we do not declare it.